# How to do async calls in PlayFramework 2 in service layer?

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework-2.0, promise

I am new to play framework 2. I have seen a lot of examples regarding async calls like:
[JavaAsync](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaAsync). However, all of them happen the "controller" layer. Meaning that the result of the functional composition is always a "Result" object in these examples, and I have not seen any other examples that return anything other than "Result". Having said this, due to a different setup i need to return a Boolean. Here is my setup:

I have a service layer. So my controller gets the request from the user, it passes it to my service layer, my service layer talks to an external service (in my case elasticsearch), the external service sends it result, my service layer gets it and passes it to the controller,... .

My problem is that my async call happens in the service layer (btw, I am using play2-elasticsearch plugin just in case):

```
    @Override
    public Boolean saveTask(TaskInfo taskInfo){
        final TaskEntity taskEntity = EntityTransformer.createNewTaskEntity(taskInfo);
        // save to es
        F.Promise indexResponsePromise = taskEntity.indexAsync();
        return indexResponsePromise.map(new F.Function() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(IndexResponse indexResponse) throws Throwable {
                if (indexResponse.getId().equals(taskEntity.id.toString())) {
                    return Boolean.TRUE;
                } else {
                    return Boolean.FALSE;
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Having, the code above, I get an error telling me that saveTask method should return a 'F.Promise'. Now the questions:

1. how can I only return a "Boolean" instead of 'F.Promise'?
2. If return 'F.Promise', how can I get the value out of it?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to have a boolean value as return using elastic search calls which are lengthy operations ?
I advice you to delete the return type and replace it with callback executed within the promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to return a Boolean would be to block the calling thread until that reply arrives which would be a bad (tm) thing.

The good option (which might seem bad at first look at it) is to let the asynchronosity leak out through your layers. So, you make your controller async and you let your service layer return F.Promise. That way you can let your controller method be fully async and react on the boolean arriving and at that point create a http reply.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a response from the Play Framework google group:

I think in order to better understand the situation, we need to take a step back.

When you operate asynchronously, you're faced with a choice.  You can either be asynchronous from end-to-end, or you can block at some point and escape asynchronicity (but at a cost!).

So to take your question, ideally `saveTake` would return an `F.Promise<Boolean>`, not a `Boolean`.  Then whatever calls `saveTask` would operate on that boolean asynchronously as well and so on until you get to the controller.  The controller would then take a `Future<Result>` rather than a simple `Result`.  At that point, that code path is asynchronous from beginning to end.  (Well, ignoring whatever else is going on in your code base)

Once you have an `F.Promise<Boolean>`, you can use various higher-order functions on `F.Promise` in order to operate asynchronously.  For instance, if you look at the API for `F.Promise`, you'll see the [`map`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html#map%28play.libs.F.Function%29) function.

You would create an `F.Function` which takes a `Boolean` as its sole input parameter and returns a `B` (for whatever `B` is since `F.Function` is generic).  This is called mapping.

Instead of operating directly on your boolean, you would chain these functions onto your promise as you go, only executing each function as the preceding result is available and all of this would be done asynchronously.